# Fields of view in Daydream View 2017

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, daydream

I've got doubts about fields of view in Daydream View 2017. I've tested my Unity app on both plugins: Cardboard and Daydream and it seems that FOV in the Daydream is even narrower than it is in the Cardboard.

According to the official data, Daydream's FOV is 100° but I'm sure it isn't. I made a test scene with several small objects, located around the camera with a 5° step. The plan was to check the FOV that is displayed on the screen and the FOV that I can really see in Google Daydream.

Here there are the Unity-scene and the screenshot of the app:

[image]

[image]

According to the screenshot horizontal FOV is approximately 95° and vertical FOV is almost 100°. That's good. The problem is that I can see only one pink circle on each side. I draw the red border to illustrate the real FOV. I think that it is about 70°.

I deny that my face is so uncommon and ugly that I cannot use Daydream View. To be sure about that I tried my app on other people with the same result.

So my question is: **is 70° a real FOV** of Google Daydream View 2017?
Or is there something wrong with Unity Daydream plugin?

Some tech details:

- Phone: Google Pixel XL
- OS: Android 8.0.0
- Unity: 2017.2.0f3

Answer (score 0):

switch your cam from perspective to orthographic and re-measure. it will do you no good to have ortho in a 3d program, but i would venture to guess in orthographic you will see all your dots. the problem is perspective itself because in perspctive mode, the number of dots you can see is determined by distance from the camera. so i guess the better question is, at what distance do you have 100 degree range.